# How async_read_some() in boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket actually works?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

It is written in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html):

> This function is used to asynchronously read data from the stream
>   socket. The function call always returns immediately.

I know it is asynchronous, so it returns immediately. But what does `async_read_some()` differ from free function read()? When I try to `std::cout` my buffer used for `async_read_some()`, it seems that the function reads many times until the stream is out of data.

Does this mean `async_read_some()` request continuously until it receives every data, for example, in a HTTP GET request? And the server will write little at a time and send a little to the client (for `async_read_some()` to read a little bit of whole data), or it dumps all data to the client at once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `async_read_some()` does not request continuously.

The `ip::tcp::socket::async_read_some()` function will make a system call that starts the read.

After that, the next time you call `io_service::run()` on the `io_service` that you passed to the constructor of the `ip::tcp::socket`, the `io_service` will check to see if the `async_read_some()` has read any data.

If data has been read, then it will call the `ReadHandler` callback that you passed to `async_read_some()`.

If data has not yet been read, it will return and check for completion again the next time you call `io_service::run()`.

Comment: So, which means read() will hang until all the data has been read from the stream?

Comment: Yes, though the usual term is 'block,' not 'hang'. `read()` will block until complete. `async_read_some()` will not block, it will return immediately, and then complete asynchronously later.

Comment: So does async_write_some work the same way as async_read_some?

Comment: Yes, async_write_some works the same way as async_read_some.

Answer (score 4):

> What does `async_read_some()` differ from free function `read()`?

As the name implies, the member method `async_read_some()` is asynchronous. The free function `read()` is not.

> I try to `std::cout` my buffer used for `async_read_some()`, it seems
>   that the function reads many times until the stream is out of data.

It will read from the stream up to the buffer size you indicate, this may or may not be done with multiple read operations.

> Does this mean `async_read_some()` request continuously until it
>   receives every data, for example, in a HTTP GET request? And the
>   server will write little at a time and send a little to the client
>   (for `async_read_some()` to read a little bit of whole data), or it
>   dumps all data to the client at once?

Not exactly. It means your application can service multiple sockets concurrently without explicit use of threads. The interactions between a server and your application are orthogonal to the use of asynchronous methods here. Your application should expect a stream of bytes. How the server is implemented does not matter to your application.